# How do I get the action name from a base controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I'd like to implement a base controller on one of my controllers.  Within that base controller, I'd like to be able to get the current executing ActionResult name.

How would I go about doing this?

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
```

And;

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    public ControllerBase()
    {
        //method which will get the executing ActionResult
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't know this in the constructor of the controller as the controller is currently being instantiated and no action could be called yet. However you could override the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) method and fetch the action name from the routing engine:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    var actionName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
}
```