# How can I use Base Controller in ASP.NET to record user actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-core

I am required to record user action and I don't want to have code in every method is every controller so would it make sense to somehow do this in the basecontroller ? OR is there a better way?

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected ILogger logger;

    public BaseController(ILogger<BaseController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //How do I get the current controller? 
        //How do I get the current method being called? 
        //How can I pass in additional parameters?
        //How can I get the user? 

        logger.LogWarning("Loaded BaseController");
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

}
```

Comment: Research action filters [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0#action-filters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

**First**: You could create your own base controller and implement `OnActionExecution` as you did. See the sample bellow to get information from `ActionExecutingContext`.

If you go this way, every controller that inhirits from this base controller will get the implementation of the logger because you are overriding `OnActionExecuting` (that applies to all actions of your controller).

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    //How do I get the current controller? 
    string controllerName = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName

    //How do I get the current method being called? 
    string actionName = context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

    //How can I pass in additional parameters?
    foreach (var parameter in context.ActionParameters)
    {
        var parameterKey = parameter.Key;
        var parameterValue = parameter.Value;
    }

    //How can I get the user? 
    var user = this.User; // IPrinciple instance, explore this object

    logger.LogWarning("Loaded BaseController");
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

**Second:** On the other hand, you can use **ActionFilters** which is a class that inhirits from `ActionFilter` class and do the same implementation on this classe overriding the `OnActionExecuting`. Then you can decorate your controllers with this attribute to make the logger. Given it is an attribute, you have to define the name fo the class with a sufix `Attribute` and use without it. For sample:

```
public class LoggerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
       // same code above
    }
}

[Logger]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
   // actions code...
}
```

**Third**: Use the same action filter class and instead of applying on all classes you want, you define it as a global action filter and it will be applied to all controllers. You have to define it on `GlobalFilter` and if you are using the default template of asp.net mvc, you can define it on the `FilterConfig.cs`, for sample:

```
filters.Add(new LoggerAttribute());
```

Comment: What is the advantage of BaseController vs. ActionFilter ? Do you have access to more parameters in one vs. the other?

Comment: Also needed to add  var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

Comment: There is no advantage. It is for differenct scenarios. If you want something global, ActionFilter defined as global is the best solution, you will never forget to add it, it is automatic because you defined it. The BaseController you can have controllers that does not inhirits from this controller and leave the logger off of them.

Answer (score 1):

**For getting controller & action names** you can use `ActionDescriptor` of `ActionExecutingContext`

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var descriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
    var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
    var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    ......
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

**Regarding User information**: controller initialisation will occur before authorisation takes place. So all of yours controllers will be created before any [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization(v=vs.108).aspx) takes place.

Approach to deal with these situations is to use [Action Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx). The [Authorize Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) is fired early than controller initialisation occur.

Have a look this articles:

- [How to get controller and action name in OnActionExecuting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535241/how-to-get-controller-and-action-name-in-onactionexecuting)
- [How do I get the action name from a base controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918671/how-do-i-get-the-action-name-from-a-base-controller)
- [Getting User Identity on my base Controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236064/getting-user-identity-on-my-base-controller-constructor)